# ODBC driver with Zend Server

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, pdo, zend-server

I just installed the Zend Server on my system and I'm trying to test my database connections. I prefer using PDO to connect my databases.

MySQL connection works very well, but when I'm trying to connect MS SQL server I got an error.

> Connection to MSSQL Server failed: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

This is the code that I'm trying to run

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('odbc:host=ip-addr; dbname=my-database', 'user', 'password');
    echo "Successfully connected to MSSQL Server";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection to MSSQL Server failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I have successfully enabled `odbc` and `pdo_odbc` in the configuration panel. I'm running this on macOS Sierra 10.12.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this tutorial](https://support.zend.com/hc/en-us/articles/218197897-Configuring-a-Linux-Server-to-Connect-to-an-MSSQL-Database-Using-ODBC), and it brought me to succeed. It's written for Linux, but I just installed Homebrew and followed the tutorial a bit adapting.